# Ring is local if all element outside maximal ideal is unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit 1 with a maximal ideal $M$.

If for arbitrary $m∈R-M$, $m$ is a unit element of $R^×$, why can we declare that $R$ is local ring ?

I know $R$ is local if only if $R -R^×$ is an ideal, possiblely we use this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No unit can lie in a proper ideal. If every element not in $M$ is a unit, what is $R\setminus R^{\times}$?

Comment: Oh, I wonder why $R−m⊆R^×$ imply $R-m＝R^×$, but every unit element of $R$ does not belong to $m$, so other inclusion holds, and we can say $R-R^×＝m$.